# Bijection transforming a circle to square of the same volume

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, volume

1. Let$ D(z, r) \subset \Bbb R^2$ be disc  and  $Q(a,\rho)= (a_1-\rho,a_1+\rho)\times(a_2-\rho,a_2+\rho)\subset \Bbb R^2 $ be a square such that
   $$|D(z,r)|= |Q(a,\rho)|$$
   Can we construct **explicitly** a bijection a continuous $\phi: D(z, r) \to Q(a, \rho)$?
2. More generally, is there a general **explicit** formula $\phi(x,y)$ on $\Bbb R^2$ such that: the image of a Disc is a square of the same volume?

That is, for given a  disc $ D(z, r) \subset \Bbb R^2$,there is square $Q(a,\rho)= (a_1-\rho,a_1+\rho)\times(a_2-\rho,a_2+\rho)\subset \Bbb R^2 $ such that $\phi: D(z, r) \to Q(a, \rho)$ is a bijection and

$$|D(z,r)|= |Q(a,\rho)|?$$

Comment: For a fixed disc/square, just choose a function that preserves angles from the centers of the disc/square and that, along each radius, stretches or shrinks the distance from the center appropriately. The second question (a "universal" such function) sounds super impossible to me ... but stranger things exist in math :p

Comment: For the second part do you mean a fixed function of the plane such that given an arbitrary disc, one can do this? Or given a disc, one can construct a function of the plane to achieve this (i.e. the function depends on the disc)?

Comment: What do you mean by the (strange to me) absolute values in $|D(z,r)|= |Q(a,\rho)|$ ? Area equality ?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1509/1509.06344.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie that is a notation for the volume

Answer (score 1):

A sketch of an answer.

Let $z\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be arbitrary and let $C(z,r)$ be a circle around $z$ with radius $r>0$. Define the function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by projecting any circle $C(z,r)$ onto the square centered at $z$ with side length $r\sqrt{\pi}$. This is clearly bijective and continuous and maps any circle centered at $z$ to a square of the same area.

Now for the more interesting question, which is what I assume you meant by part $2$ of your post. Does there exist a continuous bijection $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that maps any disc in the plane to a square with the same area?

**Claim:** Such a function cannot exist.

Assume the contrary and let $\phi$ be such a function. Fix some $\delta>0$ and consider the discs $D$ and $D'$ centered at $0$ with radii $1$ and $1-\delta$ respectively and let $C$ and $C'$ be their boundary circles. For each $0\leq \theta<2\pi$ consider the disc $D_\theta$ of radius $\frac{\delta}{2}$ tangent to both $C$ and $C'$ such that the intersection point with $C$ has argument $\theta$ and let $C_\theta$ be its boundary circle.

Now define $S,S',S_\theta$ to be the corresponding images through $\phi$ of $D,D',D_\theta$ and let $\Sigma,\Sigma',\Sigma_\theta$ be their respective boundaries. Since $\phi$ is continuous, it is not hard to see that $\Sigma=\phi(C)$ and similar for $\Sigma'$ and $\Sigma_\theta$. Also, it is clear that $S',S_\theta\subset S$ for all $\theta$. Additionally, since the areas are preserved, we must have that the side length of $S$ is $\sqrt{\pi}$, that of $S'$ is $(1-\delta)\sqrt{\pi}$ and that of $S_\theta$ is $\frac{\delta\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ (for any $\theta$).

Now, since $\phi$ is bijective, we must have that, for each $\theta$, $\Sigma_\theta\cap\Sigma$ has exactly one element and so does $\Sigma_\theta\cap\Sigma'$. Pick an arbitrary point $P\in\Sigma'$. The previous statement implies $\delta\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}<dist(P,\Sigma)<\delta\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}$ since we can construct the tangent disc $D_{\arg{\phi^{-1}(P)}}$ which will have radius $\delta\frac{1}{2}$ and therefore we can construct the corresponding tangent square $\Sigma_{\arg{\phi^{-1}(P)}}$ with radius $\delta\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

However, it is not difficult to see that no matter what the relative orientation of $\Sigma'$ is inside of $\Sigma$, there will always exist some point $P\in\Sigma'$ such that $dist(P,\Sigma)\leq \delta\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ as the side lengths of $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$ were $\sqrt{\pi}$ and $(1-\delta)\sqrt{\pi}$ respectively and since $S'\subset S$, which gives us a contradiction.

I suspect there might be a more 'measure-theoretic' approach to proving the **Claim** since it is not difficult to see that if such a $\phi$ exists, it will preserve the area of at least any shape with a piece-wise smooth boundary (by approximating the area from above and below with unions of disjoint discs to arbitrary precision).